# Angular Rxjs Subscribe this.variable undefined in Class

Tags: angular, rxjs, this, subscribe

In my Angular 7 application ive implemented some code to get the last page route to create a 'back button' style functionality. It appears to work and sets this.referringRoute when an event fires but if i try and reference this.referringRoute anywhere else in the class it is undefined.  I am using arrow functions in the observable so i would have assumed the 'this' referred to in the subscription is scoped properly to the Class this, any thoughts on where i am going wrong? thank you :)

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    referringRoute: string;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //get last page route and set to class variable
        this.router.events
            .pipe(filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
                pairwise()
            )
            .subscribe((e: any) => {
                this.referringRoute = e[0].urlAfterRedirects;
                console.log("PREVIOUS URL:", this.referringRoute); // previous url, logs as expected
            });
    }


    goBack() {
        console.debug("close called:", this.referringRoute); // this.referringRoute is always undefined
        if (this.referringRoute) {
            this.router.navigate([this.referringRoute]);
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/plants/collections']);
        }
    }
}
```

goBack is called from template like so:

```
<div (click)="goBack()">
```

Comment: How are you calling the goBack meyhod?

Comment: from template, on a div (click)="goBack()"

Comment: its getting called on click as expected, which happens much later than the subscription returning and attempting to set the this.referringRoute value

Comment: Can you just try setting a default value to referringRoute when it is declared and see if it is still getting overriden by some event or remains as is?

Comment: hey thanks for helping :) I have actually tried that, then on goBack its always set to the default value. My current hunch is that 'this' isn't scoped correctly to the parent class inside the subscribe so the class this.referringRoute never gets set but i could be wrong about that

Comment: I don't thibk scoping is an issue here. Still you can put one more property let's say test = 10; in your component and print it's value in the subscription block to see if the this is setup correctly.

Comment: Ah yes, testing test = 10 in component logs out fine within the subscribe context, you are right

Comment: This means that this.referringRoute = e[0].urlAfterRedirects; is somehow getting reassigned with undefined. Is the subscription code getting executed more then once. Did you apply a debugger there and check?